# Is it possible to pass parameters to the callback URL of a FB app which is accessed through a tab?

Tags: facebook

I have this facebook application which adds a custom tab to fan pages. You access the tab by an URL like:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE-NAME-HERE/PAGE-ID?v=APP-ID

I want to be able to add some extra get parameters to that URL, but it seems they don't get passed correctly because facebook is filtering them. Is there a way to pass those parameters? Even not via GET but some other kind of technique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple querystring params though the app_data param, you can **urlencode it**.

All querystring params that need to propagate through a Facebook tab should be url-encoded in the app_data var.

In other words, the "&" and the "=" need to be url-encoded (especially if passing more than one param).

### Examples

#### GOOD TAB URL (this passes all 3 params):

https://www.facebook.com/pages/yourpagename/56789?sk=app_12345&app_data=var1%3D123456789%26anothervar%3Drawr%26athird%3Dmeow

In the app_data from this signed request, I got this value: *var1=123456789&anothervar=rawr&athird=meow*

#### BAD TAB URL (this passes only the first param through the signed_request):

https://www.facebook.com/pages/yourpagename/12345?sk=app_56789&app_data=var1=123456789&anothervar=rawr&athird=meow

In the app_data from this signed request, I ONLY got this value: *var1=123456789* (Facebook dropped the rest)

You can even give your media team instructions like this =)

> Media team,
>
> Here is an online utility to urlencode the querysting data you want to
> embed in the app_data param: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
>
> Base Url: https://www.facebook.com/pages/yourpagename/12345?sk=app_56789&app_data=
>
> Steps:
>
> 1. Go to http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
> 2. Type var1=123456789&anothervar=rawr&athird=meow in the box
> 3. Hit the Encode button
> 4. You’ll get var1%3D123456789%26anothervar%3Drawr%26athird%3Dmeow which becomes your app_data param. Append that to the baseUrl noted above like this:
>    https://www.facebook.com/pages/yourpagename/12345?sk=app_56789&app_data=var1%3D123456789%26anothervar%3Drawr%26athird%3Dmeow (this is the URL with the tracking params for the [banner ad] [online media] [etc])

p.s. Querystring params in non-tab pages are handled fine (https://apps.facebook.com/yourappname/Canvas.aspx?var1=123456789&anothervar=rawr&athird=meow does not strip out qs params like what happens in the Tab, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the app_data parameter in the URL:

```
http://facebook.com/pages/:page_id/:page_name?sk=app_:app_id&app_data=my_data
```

You will then access it through the signed_request param. For instance with Ruby and RestGraph:

```
user = RestGraph.new.parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request)
data = user['app_data'] # => "my_data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending app_data worked for me.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPage/11111111111111?sk=app_22222222229&app_data=foo_bar

Then retrieve signed request using PHP SDK (in my case). app_data is then available in the assoc. array returned.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, in my case I had needed to pass a parameter "from" to identify if user was using mobile form or web form to login. My app use Spring Security. The way I was able to do that was creating my own SocialAuthenticationFilter:

1) Add a (hidden in my case) parameter to your login form ("from" in this example).

2) Get the right SocialAuthenticationFilter.java source (in accordance with your Spring version).

3) Create your MySocialAuthenticationFilter using it.

4) In method:
    `getRequestedProviderId(HttpServletRequest request)` is where you can
grab your parameter:

```
    private String getRequestedProviderId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String f = request.getParameter("from");
        if(f!=null) {
            final String dbValue = request.getParameter("from");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("from", dbValue);
        }
    ...
```

And thats all. In this way after a successful authentication you will be able to recover from session your parameter.
Be aware this method is called several times during OAuth exchanging, and when it is called from the authentication provider (Facebook for example) the parameter will be null. That is the reason to check the value before save in session in order to avoid delete your right value.

Answer (score -2):

I answer myself by saying this is not possible.

Comment: no, it is possible, first answer is working, you have just to remember to parse signed_request