# Facebook & Classic ASP - Passing custom parameters to fan page tab - error with no data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp-classic, base64

We have our app working using this code ([Is it possibile to pass parameters to the callback URL of a FB app which is accessed through a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634102/is-it-possibile-to-pass-parameters-to-the-callback-url-of-a-fb-app-which-is-acce)), but the issue arises when there is no app_data parameter passed in.  Here is an example of what we mean:

Works Fine: ("test" is written out fine)
https://www.facebook.com/phillypours/app_397493550309543?app_data=test

Does NOT Work:
https://www.facebook.com/phillypours/app_397493550309543

Code used with Base64 Encode & JSON Decode:

```
myArray = Split(Request("signed_request"), ".")
encoded_sig = myArray(0)
payload = myArray(1)
sig = base64_decode(Replace(encoded_sig, "-_", "+/"))
set data = JSON.parse(base64_decode(Replace(payload, "-_", "+/")))
Response.Write data.app_data
```

This is the error we receive when no parameter is passed in:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'data.app_data'
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to trap for this?  I cannot do anything with "data.app_data" since this is what throws the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you.

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this.  Wanted to share to others could benefit.  thanks, Dennis

```
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/includes/fb_base64.asp"-->
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/includes/fb_json_decode.asp"-->

Function parsePageSignedRequest()
    If Request("signed_request") <> "" Then
        myArray = Split(Request("signed_request"), ".")
        payload = myArray(1)
        payload_decoded = base64_decode(payload)
        set data = JSON.parse(payload_decoded)

        If instr(payload_decoded,"""app_data""") Then 
            AppData = data.app_data
        End If
        If instr(payload_decoded,"liked"":true,") Then
            LikeStatus = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```